# Load images from local folder using loop with error handling

Tags: jquery, image, filepath

I am trying to load images on a static web app using for-loop. I am running a nodejs http-server to run local server.

The code below isn't working and returning undefined. Can anyone point out the problem? Also, this web app running on client machine.

What I want to do, is when image file path is not valid or image not found it should set it to default.

My code is this

```
for(let i=0;i<16;i++){
  let img_src = validatePath('img/music/',i,'.svg');
   $('img').attr(src,img_src);
}

function validatePath(folder, fileindex, extention) {
    let finalPath = "";
    let path = folder + fileindex + extention;
    $.get(path)
        .done(function(data) {
            finaPath = path;
        }).fail(function(error) {
            finaPath = "img/default.svg";
        });
    return finalPath ;
}
```

**Is there any other way to do this without $.get()?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried this and it worked. This way I can return the filepath if found and default image if not found...

```
function validatePath(folder, fileindex, extension) {
    let path = folder + fileindex + extension;
    let finalPath = ""; 
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.open('HEAD', path, false);
    http.send();
    if (http.status != 404) finalPath = path;
    else finalPath = "img/default.svg"
    return finalPath;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on @Kattath 's comment, your code should look more like:

```
for(let i=0;i<16;i++){
  validatePath('img/music/',i,'.svg', function(img_src) {
      $('img').attr(src, img_src);
  });
}

function validatePath(folder, fileindex, extension, callback) {
    let path = folder + fileindex + extension;
    $.get(path)
        .done(function(data) {
            callback(path);
        }).fail(function(error) {
            callback("img/default.svg");
        });
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. Can you tell me how to use 

`let img_src = validatePath('img/music/',i,'.svg');` 

---> instead of ---> 

`validatePath('img/music/',i,'.svg', function(img_src) {
      $('img').attr(src, img_src); }` 

something like 
`let img_src = validatePath('img/music/',i,'.svg', function(img_src) {
     return img_src;
 }`

Comment: No, @Greyfrog. There is no good way to do that (and what you wrote in this comment won't work too). You will be forcing a synchronous operation on a fundamentally asynchronous operation. Read the answer linked from Kattath's comment above.